# How to show unlisten * query from pg_stat_activity in postgresql

Tags: c#, sql, linux, postgresql

When I run:

```
SELECT usename, query from pg_stat_activity where datname='testdb';
```

I get:

```
 usename  |                                query                                
----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 testuser | unlisten *
 testuser | unlisten *
 postgres | select usename, query from pg_stat_activity where datname='testdb';
```

testuser is an user for backend connection. I write backend in C# with Npgsql library.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-unlisten.html

> UNLISTEN is used to remove an existing registration for NOTIFY events.
>   UNLISTEN cancels any existing registration of the current PostgreSQL
>   session as a listener on the notification channel named channel. The
>   special wildcard * cancels all listener registrations for the current
>   session.

you cant list what behind `*`, neither what was sent to the channel

Comment: So is that impossible to show which query backend sent?

Comment: `unlisten *` is a query the backend sent, I just meant you cant find out the list of channels and actual notifies sent